# Convert Teradata SQL to BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

How do I convert following sql to bigquery?

```
SELECT
MAX(var1)*2 as name1,
name1+11 as name2
FROM table
```

In bigquery I can't use name1 if I declare it in the line above.

I know i can do this, but when sql is big then a lot needs to be changed, there may be other simpler options.

```
SELECT
MAX(var1)*2 as name1,
MAX(var1)*2+11 as name2
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse the alias in this way on BigQuery, you will have to repeat the full expression or subquery.  Assuming the former option:

```sql
SELECT MAX(var1)*2 AS name1,
       MAX(var1)*2 + 11 AS name2
FROM yourTable;
```

The only other option would be to subquery:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT MAX(var1)*2 AS name1
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT name1, name1 + 11 AS name2
FROM cte;
```

But from a performance point of view, there is an added cost which the subquery version has over the first version.  You should probably go with repeating the alias expression *unless* you really would need to repeat a lot of code.

Comment: question updated